# How do I get a list of installed voices with AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, text-to-speech

How do I get a list of installed voices with AppleScript? I see that sometime ago was used: "tell application voices" or seeing what files were in the directory "/System/Library/Speech/Voices/" but it seems that these methods don't work anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the shell script say and -v option to get the list.

```
do shell script "say -v?"
```

> -v voice, --voice=voice
>              Specify the voice to be used. Default is the voice selected in
>              System Preferences. To obtain a list of voices installed in the
>              system, specify '?' as the voice name.

On my system I will get a long list like:

```
Deranged            en_US    # I need to go on a really long vacation.
Fred                en_US    # I sure like being inside this fancy computer
Good News           en_US    # Congratulations you just won the sweepstakes and you don't have to pay income tax again.
Hysterical          en_US    # Please stop tickling me!
Jorge               es_ES    # Hola, me llamo Jorge y soy una voz española.
```

To pull just the names I will use the spaces after the names as a separator to split the names and junk

```
set the_name to do shell script "say -v? |   awk -F\"\\ \\ \" '{print $1}'"
```

So here I pipe the result from the say command to awk.

The -F fs option
       defines the input field separator to be the regular expression fs.
So this is where I use the spaces to separate the names from the junk.

I only need to give a double space and not the whole amount of space between the names and the junk. I also have to escape the spaces with a backslash each.

And because we are in Applescript  we need to actually escape the escapes to pass them onto the the shell. and of  course  escape the extra quotes.

```
\"\\ \\ \"
```

The awk {print $1}  will print out all the fields in field 1  ($1)

which gives me:

```
Deranged
Fred
Good News
Hysterical
Jorge
```

Comment: On macOS Catalina (v10.15.7) with the zsh terminal, I had to input the command as follows (Note: there is a single space between the '-v' and backslash): say -v \?